# how to concatenate variable and speical character using php

Tags: php

I want to concatenate the following two variables `$path1` and `$path2` to get `$path` and then concatenate `$path` with `$filename` to get `$fullpath`. Any help would be appreciated.

```
$path1="images"  
$path2= "\"    

$path = $path1+$path2

$fullpath=$path + $filename
```

Comment: use `.` operator to concatenate strings in php. Also make `$path = "\\";`

Answer (score 2):

```
$path1="images"  
$path2= "\\"    

$path = $path1.$path2

$fullpath=$path.$filename
```

Remember that you have to escape character `\` (using the escape character `\`). Finally string concatenation in PHP is performed using the `.` operator

Answer (score 1):

You can use concatenation operator ('.') in php.

```
$path1 = "images";  
$path2 = "\";    

$path = $path1.$path2;

$fullpath = $path.$filename;
```

Answer (score 1):

PHP uses `.` (dot) to concatenate strings, not `+`, so try that instead.

Manual reference: http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php

Answer (score 0):

You can use dot(.) for concatenate in php like

```
$path = $path1.$path2

$fullpath=$path.$filename
```